# arrays and objects efficiency

Tags: java, arrays, object, compiler-errors

test class code (where my compiler error occurs) Can't figure out how to get this to work with something of type INT, I have 3 other similar methods all with Strings that work but I know this isn't how it should be with the int, any guidance would be great!

Comment: This question has problems.  You're asking two different things (about the `for` loop and some vague compiler error).  You give no explanation as to what is wrong with the `for` loop and why it should be changed, and you give us no detail about the compiler errors.  We need a lot more detail before anyone can help you.

Comment: You need the loop to iterate through the array, unless you want a bunch of if statements to check each index

Comment: Use a HashMap! Not an array

Comment: @JosiahHester I can only use arrays and objects for this.

Comment: @nhgrif I can stick to the for loop, but there is another way to do so without it and I am just curious, but what's more important is trying to get the second portion of the code provided to work with the first and process this whole thing, I added some more insight if helpful. Thanks

Comment: That is an unfortunate constraint... You could sort the array by inventory number, then do a binary search, that would be the quickest way to find your `Book` without a HashMap.

Comment: The only thing that would be more efficient than a `for` loop (or `while` or `do while`) would possibly be a `for each` loop.

Comment: @JosiahHester hmm.. could you show what that will look like or where my existing code is wrong? like I mentioned the way it is set as of now, it works with Strings so when I search titles, authors, or categories it works fine, but because inventory is a type int it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your reply

Comment: What does the `Book.findBookByInventoryNumber()` method look like?  And is it a `static` method?

Comment: @nhgrif it is a static method, it is the first method posted before the compiler error, it is located in my object class

Comment: Oh duh.  I see.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possibly slightly better than a regular `for` loop:

```
String message = "";
for(Book book : arrayOfBooks) {
    if(inventoryNumberSearched == book.getInventoryNumber() {
        message = message + book.toString()
    }
}
```

However, it's important to note that you can't guarantee the order in which a `for each` loop iterates through your array, so if the order in which the `book.toString()` strings are appended to message matters at all, you probably shouldn't use this.

---

As for your compiler errors, this is problematic:

```
message = Book.findBookByInventoryNumber(theBooks, searchInventoryNumber);
```

Because your `findBookByInventoryNumber()` method is a `void` return type (and you're trying to send it into a string variable).

You need to change the method's return type to `String` and return a string out of it.

From your original method:

```
public static String findBookByInventoryNumber(Book[] arrayOfBooks, int inventoryNumberSearched) 
{
    String message = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < getNumberOfBooks(); i++) {
        if(inventoryNumberSearched == arrayOfBooks[i].getInventoryNumber()) {
           message = message + arrayOfBooks[i].toString();
        }//end if
    }//end for
    return message;
}//end findByInventory
```

Comment: unfortunately the order would matter, no issue, I'll stick with the for loop, if it works it works, I was just attempting to make it look a little cleaner. But the compiler error is still keeping me from seeing if a search is possible with an inventory number entry.

Comment: No one can guess at your compiler error.  You have to post it in your original question.

Comment: Can't guarantee the order?  The [JLS specification for the enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) says that on an array, it's equivalent to a conventional `for` loop that starts from 0 and iterates up to the array's length in increments of 1.  The iteration order is well-defined and guaranteed (assuming your JVM follows the spec).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking up the `Book` object by the inventory number, you should use a Map structure instead of an Array. Use a [`HashMap<int, Book>`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
public static void findBookByInventoryNumber(HashMap<int, Book> mapOfBooks, int inventoryNumberSearched)
{
    return mapOfBooks.get(inventoryNumberSearched);
}
```